# JS: how to add elastic while dragging an object?

Tags: javascript, math

i have this object div "circle"
and i move/drag it with the mouse...

how can I achieve the little elastic effect...like a bouncing...i hope you understand what i mean..like a rubber effect or some inertia

what the math formula for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the easing equations. You can find a collection of these [equations](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/ae119ce60d776085004fe3c0b9714db8f4645e78/ui/jquery.effects.core.js#L705) and [animations](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) for each one in the jquery-ui repository and homepage respectively. These are all based out of the [jquery.easing.js](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) plugin and Robert Penner's equations. You can check a book chapter about easing on [Robert Penner's homepage](http://robertpenner.com/easing/).